# Backup for windows VMs and Data

Tags: backup, data, virtual-machine

***My Setup***

Lab1 Server has two drives

M:  Data around 1.7GB

V:  VMWare Virtual Machines around 2GB

Z: I use this drive to backup both M: and V:

i used Windows Servers backup, a Full backup takes 24+ hours, i am okay with it and increment backup is not consistent, every now and then backup fails and then next day it's doing full backup again

Issue Update#1 02/24/2016

So i had a successful backup yesterday and today when i powered on my server my backup started on it's own i was hoping this would be just incremental backup and finish within minutes but it failed, with no meaningful errors
[image]

So now that it failed if i try to run another backup it's going to be a full backup again.

**Requirements**

Following are my requirements, please share Pluses and Negatives in your answer and any issues you encountered and if you are currently using the same solution and from how long

1. open source solution
2. LAN only or if it has LAN and WAN then clear and easy instructions to disable WAN
3. Stable, and continuous improving
4. Supports latest versions of OS's it's okay even if the new OS Support is in beta
5. Has file and folder exclusion list, when i backup VM's i don't want to backup temporary files, caches folder etc
6. Being able to schedule or run on demand so when i am running VM's i don't it to try to backup every tiny change

Comment: before asking, i looked at other backup question but most seems like companies trying to market their product, it would really help to know actual experience of somebody in my situation